# Django complex grouping

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Here are my models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField()

class Competition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Laureate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    competitions = models.ManyToManyField(Competition, through='LaureateCompetition')

class LaureateCompetition(models.Model):
    laureate = models.ForeignKey(Laureate)
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition)
```

I am using PostgreSQL.
I am trying to group `Laureates` based on `Location`:

```
[
    {
        "city": "Moscow",
        "laureates" : ["Bob", "Peter", "Maria"]
    },
    {
        "city": "London",
        "laureates" : ["Nicolai", "John", "Adam"]
    }
]
```

What I end up doing is looks like this:

```
locations = []
all_laureate_competitions = LaureateCompetition.objects.select_related().all()
all_competitions = Competition.objects.order_by('location')\
                                      .distinct('location')\
                                      .select_related()

for competition in list(all_competitions):
    location = competition.location
    competitions = list(set(
        [x for x in all_laureate_competitions
         if x.competition.location == location]
    ))
    laureates = list(set([x.name for x in competitions]))
    locations.append(create_location(location, laureates))
return locations
```

If I do it with SQL:

```
SELECT app_location.country,    
  (SELECT array
     ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (app_laureate.name) app_laureate.name
      FROM app_laureatecompetition
      LEFT JOIN app_laureate ON app_laureate.id = app_laureatecompetition.laureate_id
      WHERE app_laureatecompetition.competition_id IN
          (SELECT app_competition.id
           FROM app_competition
           WHERE app_location.id = app_competition.location_id) )) AS pupils
FROM app_location
```

I do not really like first approach. 
What are common practicies to do such kind of a query? Should I do it with raw sql? Is there more orm way?

Comment: It might be helpful to write the SQL before trying to write the matching Django ORM code. Once you know the SQL, you can probably figure out how to get the ORM to generate it. I make a habit of doing that. Also, it might depend on your database. You basically want to get arrays back from the database. I know that's possible out of the box with PostgreSQL and psycopg2, but I don't know about other databases.

Comment: @jpmc26 I expressed it in SQL. Please check the edit.

Comment: I meant the query you want to have, that includes the `GROUP BY`. If your database can't return an array, you're pretty much stuck doing it in Python like you are.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want a list of Laureates per location?

Comment: @rednaw Yes. The json above is what I want.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes it is allowed to get arrays.

Comment: @VladimirNani What database technology are you using? I've had much success using the `ARRAY_AGG` for this kind of query in PostgreSQL. If there's an aggregate function you can use, it might simplify your query and present a simpler way of incorporating it with the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this:

```
results = []

for location in Location.objects.all():
    for competition in location.competition_set.all():
        for laurete_competition in competition.laurete_competition_set.all():
            results.append(laurete_competition.laurete_set.all())

print results
```

Also see the excelent Django documentation, I always go there when I have a similar problem:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships